# Finding lower bound of probability with Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I know that Chebyshev's inequality is $$\Bbb P(|X-\mu|\ge c)\le\frac{\sigma^2}{c^2}$$ for all $c\ge0$, and in the given problem, $\Bbb E[X]=7$ and $\sigma^2=9$. The problem asks to find a lower bound for the probability $$\Bbb P(4<X<10)$$

I have just been introduced to Chebyshev's inequality and am wondering how exactly to apply it in this case?

Comment: Hint: $7-4=3$ and $10-7=3$

Comment: I see that that is the standard deviation; still don't see how to work this out

Answer (score 0):

Proceed like this:
$$\Bbb{P}(4<X<10) = \Bbb{P}(|X-\mu|<3) = 1-\Bbb{P}(|X-\mu|\geq3)\geq1-\frac{\sigma^2}{c^2}=1-\frac99=0$$

Comment: Yes, though this is not very helpful since all probabilities are non-negative.  We could go further and say that $0 \le \Bbb P(4 \lt X \lt 10) \lt 1$ with all values possible in this half-open interval.